# How do i use getStdGen in a function

Tags: haskell, random

I'm new to haskell, especially the Random type, and I was looking through learnyouahaskell tutorials when I came across this

```
import System.Random  

main = do  
    gen <- getStdGen  
    putStr $ take 20 (randomRs ('a','z') gen)
```

However, when I try to use this in a function, this fails (i.e)

```
genrandTF:: Int -> StdGen -> [Bool]
genrandTF number gen =  take number (randomRs (True, False) gen)
```

and calling it via

```
genrandTF 20 getStdGen
```

why is that?

-update-

The error I'm getting is

```
<interactive>:116:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `StdGen' with actual type `IO StdGen'
    In the second argument of `genrandTF', namely `(getStdGen)'
    In the expression: genrandTF 20 (getStdGen)
```

When I change it to type IO StdGen, I'm unable to compile as I get this message:

```
No instance for (RandomGen (IO StdGen))
  arising from a use of `randomRs'
In the second argument of `take', namely
  `(randomRs (True, False) gen)'
In the expression: take number (randomRs (True, False) gen)
In an equation for `genrandTF':
    genrandTF number gen = take number (randomRs (True, False) gen)
```

Comment: You need to post your error message.  Can you provide a copy and paste of what your are typing in and what you are seeing back?

Comment: ``getStdGen`` has type ``IO StdGen``, but you are using it as if it has type ``StdGen``. You will need to read more about monads.

Comment: updated the question-- tried to use IO StdGens, but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common mistake of beginners. `getStdGen` is a value which has the type `IO StdGen`; in other words it is not a `StdGen` but rather a computer program which, when it completes, will contain something which Haskell can use as a `StdGen`.

You'll need to either run the program to get the `StdGen` (via `unsafePerformIO` -- as the name implies this breaks several safety guarantees in Haskell), or you'll need to combine the function with the program to make a new program. (Idiomatically, Haskell I/O is a bunch of Haskell operations interleaved with I/O operations.)

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do would be:

```
fmap (genrandTF 20) getStdGen
```

which uses the `Functor` instance for `IO`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but I'm assuming this isnt returning a [Bool] type? Is there any possible way to convert it back to [Bool] ?

Comment: It gives you an `IO [Bool]`, that is, a program which when it completes, will contain something which Haskell can use as a `[Bool]`. In general you cannot "escape" this IO wrapper without `unsafePerformIO` (since escaping it intrinsically voids referential transparency in many many cases), but you can put arbitrary Haskell code into the IO wrapper with an operator `(>>=) :: IO x -> (x -> IO y) -> IO y` (it takes a program which makes an x, and a Haskell function from x's to programs that make y's, and knits them together into a program which makes a y). This is the way `do`-notation works.

Answer (score -2):

From [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.2/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomR) for `randomR` (which `randomRs` uses internally):

> It is unspecified what happens if lo>hi

(when calling it as in `randomR (lo,hi)`.

Now `True > False`, so you're running into unspecified behaviour here. Try using `(False,True)` (in addition to fixing the `IO`-related errors).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This answers a question that the author might come up with once he fixes that problem. If you have something to say about a question that isn't an answer, post it as a comment.

Comment: @Cubic: You're right, of course - I typed up this answer without checking what the actual problem was (and when the only information provided was 'this fails', but that's not a good excuse). Ah well, I'll let it stand and hope some good comes out of it.